# Internationalization-packages for Scene-Builder?

Tags: internationalization, scenebuilder

I saw the possibility to change the Internationalization of Scene Builder. But I did not find somewhere suitable language packages. May somebody of you have been faced by same kind of intention? For any hints in this matter I would be grateful.
With best regards

Peter

Comment: Thank you very much. :) Actually I see I did not use the right words to express my intention. Sorry for this. I intent to change the language used within of Scene builder from English to German. That means, the whole menu of Scene-builder I would like to  change to German. Sorry for any confusing I caused. But you are right, I should google much more intensively in before of posting such question. Beside of, thank you for the hint you sent.

Answer (score 0):

I checked by the way the possibility to change the language of the scene-builder-menu with use of google. The result of my investigation is: **It is not possible to be done by a standard kind of user.** Sorry, I did not expect this result. Anyway, I learned by. Thank you very much for the time an efforts you spend to bring me onto the right way to get an answer in regard to the question i did publish in before. Thank you.